# Numbering equations in Latex

Tags: numbering, equation-number

I am writing a document in Latex (documentclass report) in which I use only chapters and sections (no subsections). However, the numbering of equations takes in account the subsection (e.g. the first equation, in the first section of the first chapter is numbered 1.1.0.1).

How can I remove that zero?

Comment: Could you please show your document

Comment: The default equation numbering defined in the standard `report` is `<chapeter>.<equation>` where equation counter gets reset after the next chapter begins. You should show your code, so we can compile it and identify problems. You could also try to insert  `\AtBeginDocument{\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}}` in preamble.

Comment: Your claim that "I use only chapters and sections (no subsections). However, the numbering of equations takes in account the subsection" seems to contradict itself: If your document doesn't use `\subsection` directives, how can the `equation` counter depend on what the subsection counter's value is? Is the value of the `subsection` counter that's displayed as part of the `equation` number perhaps always equal to `0`? Please confirm that your document's preamble contains an instruction akin to either `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` or `\counterwithin{equation}{subsection}`.

Comment: Welcome to TSE! If you define the equation counter based on the chapter and section numbering and the equation comes before the section there is chance to get zero. So obviously, If you define a section based equation then the equation should come after any section will have proper numbering.

Comment: Mico's answer solved my problem, thank you very much!